# Error in select query merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge three values in one column in select query, except `getdate` function the query is working fine, but when I write `getdate()` it gives the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FA/118,' to data
>   type int

Here is the query which is raising the error:

```
select top 1 ([Casetype] +'/'+ CaseNo +','+ YEAR(GETDATE()) )as CaseNo
from tbl_RecordRequisition
where Casetype='FA'
order by id desc
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
select top 1 ([Casetype] +'/'+ convert(varchar(50),CaseNo) +','+ convert(varchar(50),YEAR(GETDATE())) )as CaseNo from tbl_RecordRequisition where Casetype='FA' order by id desc
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to convert the value of YEAR(GETDATE()))  to a string:

```
select top 1 ([Casetype] +'/'+ CaseNo +','+ CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(GETDATE())) )as CaseNo from tbl_RecordRequisition where Casetype='FA' order by id desc
```

Otherwise sql-server tries to convert the value of the expression `([Casetype] +'/'+ CaseNo +','` to an int.

Comment: Ran this query in MS SQL Server to verify that it is working: Select 'FA/118,' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(GETDATE())) AS CaseNo

Comment: @SimplyInk Have done it in sqlfiddle and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concat the `varchar` but the `YEAR()` returns `int`

```
select top 1 
    ([Casetype] +'/'+ CaseNo +','+ CONVERT(char(4), YEAR(GETDATE()))) as CaseNo 
from tbl_RecordRequisition 
where Casetype='FA' 
order by id desc
```